# How do I unload a view controller within a Tab Bar?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a Tab Bar Controller with two views (and two buttons at the bottom to match). When I am in the second view, and press the first button, I want to not simply hide the second view, but unload it entirely until it is accessed again.

How, and where (from which end of the view-changing process-- in the tab bar's firstButtonPressed method, in the first view's ViewWillAppear method, etc.) should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this to save memory, or for a UX reason?  If the first is the case, and you are nil-ing out non-weak IBOutlet properties on viewDidUnload, you are good to go.  Whenever the OS decides it needs more memory, it will start dumping out views that are not on-screen.

If the second is the case, do what you need in the viewDidDisappear method of the class you want to trash (i.e. remove from superviews and nil as needed).

Comment: In this case I am doing this for user experience, but it is also good to know that such possible memory problems are being handled. Thanks!